# Spreadsheetgear C# - Calculate SHA hash of VBA code

Tags: c#, macros, spreadsheetgear

I need to compare macros between two spreadsheet to find if they are same.
I have to read excel using Spreadsheetgear in C#.
We are computing SHA hash for comparing cells.
I am not sure how to read Macro code as object so that hash can be calculated.
Any pointers will be great help.

Comment: Can you read it at all? If so, what kind of format can you read it in?

Comment: Actually I do not know, for referencing worksheet I can write workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"] however macro will be under modules and I do not know how to reference them.

Comment: SpreadsheetGear only supports preserving macros as-is in the file format, and no API is provides to access this part of the file, so SpreadsheetGear will not be able to help with this task, unfortunately.  You’ll have to use some other product or approach outside of SpreadsheetGear to do so, though I’m not familiar enough with any to provide suggestions.  Hopefully someone else on here can chime in with alternatives...